# Specific problem with NDSolve step size, stiffness

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, nonlinear

I am trying to solve a non-linear second order boundary value problem in a finite interval. The differential equation is $$y''-\frac{a}{b}y-\frac{u_n}{b}y^3-\frac{ge_0}{b}x=0,$$ with $x\in[0,L]$, along with the boundary conditions, $$y'(0)-\frac{o}{b}y(0)=0,\qquad y'(L)+\frac{l}{b}y(L)=\frac{ge_0L}{b}.$$
In the code attached below, with the chosen parameters, the solution is regular and shows up until $a=1.2$. On using $a=1.3$ and beyond, I get the error "At x == 0.99505895226764`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected."

I am changing the input right after $z$ in Plot[Evaluate...

Working:

```
ClearAll;
Clear[Derivative]
fneeonnd[z_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, o_?NumericQ, 
  l_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ, 
  un_?NumericQ, eo_?NumericQ] := (
  ss = NDSolve[{y''[x] - (a/b)*y[x] - (un/b)*(y[x])^3 - (g*eo/b)*x == 
      0, y'[0] - (o/b)*y[0] == 0, y'[L] + (l/b)*y[L] == (g*eo*L/b)}, 
    y, {x, 0, L}
    , Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 100]; 
  y[z] /. ss)
Plot[Evaluate[
  fneeonnd[z, 1.2, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 1]], {z, 0, 
  1}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.007]}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, 
 Frame -> {True}, FrameLabel -> {"z", \[Eta]}, 
 FrameStyle -> {{Black, Directive[Thick]}, {Black, 
    Directive[Thick]}, {Black, Directive[Thick]}, {Black, 
    Directive[Thick]}}]
```

NOT Working:

```
ClearAll;
Clear[Derivative]
fneeonnd[z_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, o_?NumericQ, 
  l_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ, 
  un_?NumericQ, eo_?NumericQ] := (
  ss = NDSolve[{y''[x] - (a/b)*y[x] - (un/b)*(y[x])^3 - (g*eo/b)*x == 
      0, y'[0] - (o/b)*y[0] == 0, y'[L] + (l/b)*y[L] == (g*eo*L/b)}, 
    y, {x, 0, L}
    , Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 100]; 
  y[z] /. ss)
Plot[Evaluate[
  fneeonnd[z, 1.3, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 1]], {z, 0, 
  1}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.007]}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, 
 Frame -> {True}, FrameLabel -> {"z", \[Eta]}, 
 FrameStyle -> {{Black, Directive[Thick]}, {Black, 
    Directive[Thick]}, {Black, Directive[Thick]}, {Black, 
    Directive[Thick]}}]
```

[image: a=1.25]
[image: a=1]
[image: a=0.5]

Comment: Look at your ODE.  The main terms are: y'' = y^3. What does this mean? y'' has to to with the curvature, that is, if y>0, the larger y, the more it is upwards bent and the faster it grows. The same for y<0. Therefor you can solve only for values where y stays small.

Comment: As far as I could see, y was actually getting smaller as I was increasing the input a. One can obtain the plots for a=0.5,0.75...1.2 to see this.

Comment: As Daniel Huber says, curvature explodes at certain x. It shows to depend strongly on parameter b. Chose b == .006 and you can go up with a to a ==2 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, `Method -> "Shooting"` with a good guess for the "StartingInitialConditions" is necessary to solve ODE boundary value problems.  Here, we use a similar do-it-yourself shooting approach.  As an example, use the parameters given for the "not working" case in the question:

```
{a, b, o, l, g, L, c, u, un, eo} =
    {1.3, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 1};

sp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] - (a/b)*y[x] - (un/b)*(y[x])^3 - (g*eo/b)*x == 0, 
    y'[0] - (o/b)*y[0] == 0, y[0] == y0}, {y[x], y'[L] + (l/b)*y[L] - (g*eo*L/b)}, 
    {x, 0, L}, {y0}];

FindRoot[Last[sp[y00]], {y00, -.02}, Evaluated -> False]
First[sp[y00 /. %]];
Plot[%, {x, 0, L}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> All]
(* {y00 -> -0.041088} *)
```

[image]

Of course, a reasonable guess is needed for `y00` in `FindRoot`, here somewhere in the range `{-.01, -.08}`.  A more ambitious case, `a = 3`, also works, yielding

```
(* {y00 -> -0.0163729} *)
```

[image]

**Addendum: Simplified Approach**

It turns out that solving the linearized ODE yields a sufficiently good seeding for the standard `Method -> "Shooting"` to produce solutions of the nonlinear ODE for all values of `a`.  The example below provides results for interger values of `a` between `0` and `10`.

```
Clear[a]; 
Table[
    tem = DSolveValue[{y''[x] - (a/b)*y[x] - (g*eo/b)*x == 0, 
    y'[0] - (o/b)*y[0] == 0, y'[L] + (l/b)*y[L] == (g*eo*L/b)}, y[0], {x, 0, L}];
    NDSolveValue[{y''[x] - (a/b)*y[x] - (un/b)*(y[x])^3 - (g*eo/b)*x == 0, 
    y'[0] - (o/b)*y[0] == 0, y'[L] + (l/b)*y[L] == (g*eo*L/b)}, y[x], {x, 0, L}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[0] == tem, 
    y'[0] == (o/b) y[0]}}], {a, 0, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate@%, {x, 0, L}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[Range[0, 10], {.3, .6}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One can use the FEM method or use the FEM method to find good starting initial conditions.  I do the latter in `fneeonnd` but save the FEM solution in `solFEM`. The check at the end shows that the shooting method did a better job of satisfying the boundary conditions.

```
fneeonnd[z_, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, o_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ, 
  g_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ, un_?NumericQ, 
  eo_?NumericQ] := (
  Clear[x, y];
  solFEM = 
   NDSolveValue[{y''[x] - (a/b)*y[x] - (un/b)*(y[x])^3 - (g*eo/b)*x ==
       NeumannValue[(o/b)*y[x], x == 0] + 
       NeumannValue[-(g*eo*L/b) + (l/b)*y[x], x == L]}, 
    y, {x} \[Element] Line[{{0}, {L}}]];
  NDSolveValue[
    {y''[x] - (a/b)*y[x] - (un/b)*(y[x])^3 - (g*eo/b)*x == 0,
     bcs = {y'[0] - (o/b)*y[0] == 0, y'[L] + (l/b)*y[L] == (g*eo*L/b)}}, 
   y, {x, 0, L}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[0] == solFEM[0], 
       y'[0] == solFEM'[0]}}(*,WorkingPrecision\[Rule]100*)])

solFN = fneeonnd[z, 1.3, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 1];
Plot[solFN[z], {z, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.007]}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, Frame -> {True}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"z", \[Eta]}, 
 FrameStyle -> {{Black, Directive[Thick]}, {Black, 
    Directive[Thick]}, {Black, Directive[Thick]}, {Black, 
    Directive[Thick]}}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{solFN[z], solFEM[z]}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
bcs /. Equal -> Subtract /. {{y -> solFN}, {y -> solFEM}}
(*  {{0., 2.55954*10^-6},        <-- Shooting
     {-0.00153343, -0.0726405}}  <-- FEM      *)
```